# Spring & JUnit: Spring instantiates two instances of test class, only injects dependencies for one, runs the other one

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection

**What I'm trying to do**: Run a single JUnit test (one JUnit test class with a single test method). Test class has one dependency that I expect Spring to handle (inject) prior to running the test.

**What I see**: Test class is instantiated twice, dependency is satisfied (injected) for one of the instances but not the other. Test is run using the instance for which dependencies are **not** injected.

**My guess**: I'm speculating that the test class is instantiated twice because Spring is using the first instance to analyze dependencies (probably using reflection to look for annotations, which I'm not using).

**But**: I cannot for my life figure out why the test class instance for which the dependency is not created/injected is used to run the test.

**test.xml**

```
<beans ...>
  <bean id="test" class="com.example.MyTestClass">
    <property name="primaryDependency" ref="pridep"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="pridep" class="com.example.MyPrimaryDependency">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="ds" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
</beans>
```

**MyTestClass.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:test.xml"})
public class MyTestClass {

  private IPrimaryDependency  mDep = null;

  public MyTestClass() {
  }

  public void setPrimaryDependency(IPrimaryDependency dep) {
    mDep = dep;
  }

  @Before
  public void createImageData() {
  }

  @Test
  public void testImageSearch() {
    assertNotNull("mDep is null", mDep);
  }
}
```

**MyPrimaryDependency.java**

```
public class MyPrimaryDependency extends RequiresADataSource implements IPrimaryDependency {

  public MyPrimaryDependency() {
  }
}
```

**Existing related question**: [Spring dependency injection null when running a test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776847/spring-dependency-injection-null-when-running-a-test-case), but I'm not able to discern what's going on from that answer.

Sorry for the rookie question-- I've been scouring documentation (and bothering colleagues) for several days and am baffled by this.

Thanks!

Comment: As @anttix suggest, adding `@Autowired` annotation to the property will correct your problem additionally, the test is already instanced by the test runner so you do not have to include it in test.xml

Comment: Hi @rbernabe-- thanks for this. 'appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add @Autowired

```
@Autowired
private IPrimaryDependency mDep;
```

Explanation:

JUnit creates brand new instances of test classes for each test.
Spring JUnit runner only extends this behaviour by "preparing" created objects which basically means setting up application context and injecting annotation driven dependencies.

In your case the test class is instantiated twice: From test.xml (the property is injected there) and by JUnit runner to run the first test method.
However when created by JUnit, Spring has no idea that it needs to inject something because there are no annotations in the class thus the property ends up being null.

See source code of [SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-test/3.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java#SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest%28%29) and [DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-test/3.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/test/context/support/DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java#DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies%28org.springframework.test.context.TestContext%29) for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Isn't the `@Autowired` annotation redundant given the bean property definition in `test.xml`?

Comment: I tend to side with @sotirios-delimianolis here and claim that test class is instantiated twice. Once by test.xml and second time the test runner instantiates it and this is where the bean is not injected if it's not annotation-driven. You can easily test it by adding System.out.println into test class constructor. Let us know how it goes ;)

Comment: So an annotation-driven bean behaves differently than one who's dependencies are specified in the `<beans>` portion of an application context xml file? This surprises me-- time to do some more reading. Thanks.

Comment: Beans themselves do not but if that bean is also a test and you combine java with XML that controls how bean properties are populated, then yes they do ;) See link to test runner source code. In principle spring should make unit tests prototype scoped beans and use beanfactory to instantiate, but if you look at the source at grepcode it's not actually the case.

Comment: Thanks @anttix-- totally appreciate this. You've helped me learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your test class is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:test.xml"})
public class MyTestClass {
```

You run this class with JUnit. Because of `@RunWith`, JUnit uses an instance of `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to instantiate the class and run its tests.

Because of `@ContextConfiguration`, the `ClassRunner` will generate an `ApplicationContext` by loading your `test.xml` file.

That `test.xml` file has a `<bean>` definition for your test class

```
<bean id="test" class="com.example.MyTestClass">
    <property name="primaryDependency" ref="pridep"/>
</bean>
```

So Spring will also generate an instance and set the appropriate property.

---

Basically, what I'm getting at is that your test class shouldn't be a bean in the Spring context. Create a different test class and inject the bean that has an injection target and inject that into your test class.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I believe, based on your answer, that I now understand what's happening. But it surprises me. I would have guessed that (and am looking for) spring/junit to cooperate and inject the test's dependencies prior to running the test. So I'd expect (I think) for spring to instantiate the test class, satisfy/inject its dependencies and then hand that instance off to JUnit for execution. Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to revise my expectation? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @jsinnott The `MyTestClass` instance generated to run the tests is completely unrelated to the `bean` instance. Spring scans the test instance and doesn't see any injection targets to process.

Comment: Hi @sotirios-delimanolis-- thanks very much for taking the time to answer. You've been a huge help.